# What disables the 'Startup type' dropdown in the services.msc snap-in, for the gamingservices and gamingservicesnet services?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, services

I've met my share of difficult Microsoft services that don't want to be fiddled with for various reasons, but I can't seem to figure out the gamingservices & gamingservicesnet services. I've added my account to their permissions in the registry. Ensured I have Full Control to the executables that the services point to. Tried editing the Type, ErrorControl, PackageOrigin, ServiceSidType and Security keys from within the registry, hoping maybe they held the answer. None of my usual suspects work, and now I'm hooked as to why.

I know I could just as easily regedit the Start key to set them manually, but I'm interested in finding out what is keeping the dropdown disabled inside the services snap-in for these two? (and thus also causing sc and Set-Service commands to fail when trying to change them)

*edit: ty Gantendo for reminding me, less is more.*
(Included is an image of the gamingservices.exe properties, just in case this is somehow version dependent)

[image: properties pane for gamingservices.exe]

Comment: XY problem much?

Comment: I'm afraid to even ask what that means, Gantendo?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Oh, that's an actual thing! Ya, I was a lil tired when I wrote this, it's a bit over the top. Wanted to include what I had tried jic someone who was equally stumped, wanted to compare notes. There's also a lot of answers on SE about services, that don't work on this particular service or focus on the solution rather than the why. Seems in trying to be clear, I've over-engineered. I'm interested in what disables that dropdown within the services.msc, rather than changing it in some other way.